# gmaven grails project not using maven-war-plugin

Tags: grails, maven, maven-war-plugin, grails-maven

I'm having issues with a filtered context.xml file being packaged in a mvn grails:war execution.

I have it working when you do mvn war:war but doing that doesn't create my grails application war.  When running mvn grails:war I don't get the context.xml file.  Is this a case of the grails:war target not running the maven-war-plugin?  I'm getting no errors.  Any help is appreciated.  Here are my relevant pom settings:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/context.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>init</goal>
                        <goal>maven-clean</goal>
                        <goal>validate</goal>
                        <goal>config-directories</goal>
                        <goal>maven-compile</goal>
                        <goal>maven-test</goal>
                        <goal>maven-war</goal>
                        <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
    <filters>
        <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/dev.properties</filter>
    </filters>
```

Answer (score 0):

grails:war uses grails command so generate war, so it will ignore anything you configured in the "maven war plugin". You will have to configure it within grails.